# Ant design Button component loads with empty style initially

Tags: next.js, antd, next.js13, web-frontend, ant-design-pro

I am using Next.js with Ant Design. After I build my project and started running it, the button appears with no style ( no bgcolor or text color ). Only after a page refresh it shows the styles. Later for each button customization, the page needs a reload for the button to appear with its styles.

Why it's happening and how to solve it?

[Initial Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1YNH.png)

[After a refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mp24.png)

My index.tsx

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Montserrat } from "next/font/google";
import React from "react";
import HomePage from "../components/Home/AforcHome";

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const montserrat = Montserrat({ subsets: ["cyrillic"] });

const Home = () => (
  <main className={`App ${montserrat.className}`}>
    <HomePage />
  </main>
);

export default Home;
```

My _app.tsx

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import React from "react";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import theme from "../theme/themeConfig";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => (
  <ConfigProvider theme={theme}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ConfigProvider>
);

export default App;
```

My _document.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";
import Document, { Head, Html, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import type { DocumentContext } from "next/document";

const MyDocument = () => (
  <Html lang="en">
    <Head />
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
);

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx: DocumentContext) => {
  const cache = createCache();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App: any) => (props: any) =>
        (
          <StyleProvider cache={cache}>
            <App {...props} />
          </StyleProvider>
        ),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  const style = extractStyle(cache, true);
  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: (
      <>
        {initialProps.styles}
        <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style }} />
      </>
    ),
  };
};

export default MyDocument;
```

The button component

```
<Form.Item
                  wrapperCol={{ span: 24, offset: 0 }}
                  className=" text-center"
                >
                  <ConfigProvider
                    theme={{
                      token: {
                        colorPrimary: "#444690",
                        colorTextLightSolid: "#ffffff",
                        borderRadius: 4,
                      },
                      components: {
                        Button: {
                          fontWeight: "medium",
                        },
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button type="primary">Register</Button>
                  </ConfigProvider>
                </Form.Item>
```

Comment: have you tried this- https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components